# Preg_replace multiple patterns

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm busy with a website and for an element I use preg_replace to replace all the spaces with a dash.

```
preg_replace('/\\s/', '-', $item_replace_en[0])
```

And this works great but now i have a new problem. A user enterd the following "Music / Film".
the output is "Music-/-Film" and i want it to be "Music-Film".

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you going to ask again when a user enters "Music, Film"? If not, take the time to specify what you want more accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to generate a string that can be used as a URL.

There a numerous of scenarios that can happen when a user adds a title that you want to convert to a URL safe string. Someone could for instance use this:

```
Mess'd up --text-- just (to) stress /test/ ?our! `little` \\clean\\
url fun.ction!?-->");
```

Should return:

> messd-up-text-just-to-stress-test-our-little-clean-url-function

Is your code ready for that? In that case you can use this function:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array in pattern and replacement text.
For example

```
$pattern=array();
$pattern[0]="/\\s/";
$pattern[1]="/-\/-/";
$replace=array();
$replace[0]="-";
$replace[1]="-";
preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $item_replace_en[0]);
```

You can use as many patterns and replacement you want.
For more info, refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$returnValue = preg_replace('/(\\s\\/)?(\\s)/', '-',$item_replace_en[0]);
```

But this will not replace a string like `"Music/ Film"` or `"Music /Film"` or `Music/Film`.